# Is there any possible way to create a Certificate with more than 2 years?

Tags: single-sign-on, certificates

For single-sign-on authenticate, a certificate is being made but it has only 1 year of expiry. That's why the user is getting an email regarding expiry. Is there any other way out for automatic renewal of expiry certificate?

Answer (score 1):

When creating self-signed certificates from the Certificate and Key Management in Salesforce:

Certificates with 2048-bit keys last one year and are faster than certificates with 4096-bit keys. 
Certificates with 4096-bit keys last two years.